# Count the numbers of rows of CSV files that were successfully imported without counting the headers

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, count, rows

I need to import a CSV files using PHP into the database. 
After the files have been successfully imported, I need to display a message with the number of rows that were successfully imported into the database. However, right now I am using `count = 0` and `count++` in the while loop.

It counts the number of rows including the headers which were not supposed to be the right answer.

Can anyone tell me how am I able to count the number of records that were successfully imported to the database?

Comment: just increment when you insert in your db

Comment: It sounds like you know how many header lines there are so simply reduce the value of count by that value after your loop.